# Can't set the path of the NDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk

I need to set the path of NDK in my Android, I am trying to do that by going to **file=>project structure** but it looks like shown below
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I15dh.jpg)

so I can't edit it or set it.
How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you tried editing the `local.properties` file directly instead?

Comment: No, How can l edit it, please?

Comment: Open the file and add a row that says `ndk.dir=C\:\\some\\directory` (where you replace `C\:\\some\\directory` with the actual NDK path on your computer).